# Sqlite form of query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i  have an issue with both functions

```
// Insert a new contact in database
public void insertInSignature(String TITLE_SI) {
    try {
        // Open Android Database
        Boolean b = checkIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot("DELIVERY_SLIP",
                "TITLE_SI", TITLE_SI);
        if(b==false)
        {
        // cursor is empty
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("TITLE_SI", TITLE_SI);
        db.insertWithOnConflict("DELIVERY_SLIP", null, initialValues,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        Log.e(TAG, "insertUser Error");
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + sqle);
    } finally {
        // Close Android Database
        databaseHelper.close();
    }
}

public boolean checkIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,
        String dbfield, String fieldValue) {
    db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + "="
            + "`"+ fieldValue+"`";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have this function , I'm inserting signature when it's not on the database.. But the function boolean return an SQLexception i don't know why i found informations about the form , but not for my problem.

Here my log.
http://hpics.li/0ae4ba2

I just want to know if the row exist on my database

here my table.

http://hpics.li/1fd3d9a

Thanks by advance if you need for informations ask me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, strings are delimited with single quotes `'`, not backticks `` ` ``.

To avoid such formatting problems, and SQL injections, you should use parameters instead:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + dbfield + "= ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { fieldValue });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a query every time you want to insert, why not make the `TITLE_SI` column `UNIQUE` with `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` or `ONC CONFLICT REPLACE`? Then you don't need to check, you simply insert and let the uniqueness constraint manage this for you.

Comment: Thanks , i use both of your response , if i could accept both i will do it.